# create a constraint on a column, but only for a part of the data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to create a constraint on a column, but only for a part of the data.

The situation is this: we have all the values for all dropdowns in one table. To separate them we have a discriminator called `dropdowntype`.

Now I want to create a constraint, but it has to take the `dropdowntype` into account.

The constraint is: dropdowns can have a default value. There is only zero or one record allowed, per dropdowntype, which has the value `true` for `isdefault`.

So there can be multiple records with the value `true` for `isdefault`, but they should all have a different value for `dropdowntype`.

EDIT:There are however multiple values allowed for a given `dropdowntype` with the value false.

Is this possible to do?

(then as a bonus, I would also like to put a constraint on another `nullable` column, that all values for that column are either null or have a value, again for a given `dropdowntype`. But maybe when the first question is answered, I'll figure out how to do this one myself.)

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DropDownValues](

    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [IsDefaultValue] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
    [IsOtherItem] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Dropdowntype] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ddv] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Comment: Probably a filtered, unique index: `create unique index on DropDownValues (dropdowntype) where IsDefaultValue = true`

Comment: Your problem isn't resolved yet?

Comment: @TT. I'm working on it. I thought the code in the comment would not have the desired result so I edited the question. I think it works, but I can't seem to find the MS Sql docs to understand WHY this works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer question 1, you want a compound unique key on `dropdowntype` and `isdefault`.  Pseudo code:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX idx_yourcolumn_notnull
ON YourTable(dropdowntype, isdefault)
WHERE isdefault IS NOT NULL;
```

You can do the same for the 2nd part of your question.  They key is the **WHERE isDefault IS NOT NULL**, ths allows you to create a unique constraint on a nullable column.

Comment: Thanks, this works. It took me a while to get my head around the syntax.